# Twitter bootstrap prevent event from taking place

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to return false/preventDefault before the `hide` event for the [collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) plugin?

E.g I want to do something like this:

```
$(".collapse").on('hide', function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass("in"))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

This simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/ujgSC/4/ with an accordion, I want to prevent the user from closing all of the accordions by clicking the same item twice.

Comment: If you click the titles a few items you will find that it half works/breaks everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try prevent event the titles.

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){    
   if($($(this).attr('href')).hasClass("in")){        
     console.log('PREVENT');
     return false;
   }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ujgSC/6/)